# How to convert longitudal data to connection data?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I have data in a form of:

```
id state
1  s_1
1  s_2
1  s_3
2  s_1
2  s_3
3  s_1
3  s_2
```

And I'd like to have it in connecion data frame:

```
source target freq
s_1    s_2    2
s_1    s_3    1
s_2    s_3    1
```

I already know I can calculate the frequencies by using plyr::count(), but how to reflow the data into source and target type?

Comment: Not the solution, but as a start: you are looking for all possible combinations between the state values. And then loop through these combinations and calculate the frequencies. There's a `combn` function in R to get the combinations.

Comment: This might help: [Expanding a list to include all possible pairwise combinations within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276418/expanding-a-list-to-include-all-possible-pairwise-combinations-within-a-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could try this with `dplyr`. As mentioned in comments, use `combn` to get pair combinations within each `id`. Afterwards, grouping by source and target you can `summarise` and get frequencies of each combination.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(as.data.frame(t(combn(.$state, m = 2)))) %>%
  setNames(c("id", "source", "target")) %>%
  group_by(source, target) %>%
  summarise(freq = n())
```

**Output**

```
  source target  freq
  <chr>  <chr>  <int>
1 s_1    s_2        2
2 s_1    s_3        2
3 s_2    s_3        1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Ben's solution is the clearest we can achieve here but for the sake of industriousness I created my solution based on comments and using for loops:

```
res <- data.frame(source=NA, target=NA)

for (i in 1:unique(df$id){
  df_grouped <- df[df$id == i,]
  for (j in 1:nrow(df_grouped)){
    source <- df_grouped[j, "state"]
    target <- df_grouped[j+1, "state"]
    res <- rbind(res, cbind(source,target))
  }
}
res <- res[complete.cases(res),]
res <- plyr::count(res)
res
```